# automatically start an EC2 instance when a request is made

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have website that I access very infrequently (sometimes 2/3 times a day and sometimes none)

I would like to automatically shutdown the instance as soon as no traffic happen (this would be possible when setting a cloudwatch alarm).

The current issue I have is that I would like to start the instance again as soon as there is a request on the website (I don't mind at all having to wait for the instance to come back online).

Is there any way of doing that? If yes how would that work technically?

Comment: Can you explain: `as soon as there is a request on the website` ? When the website is not running, how will there be a request? How do you detect a request is pending?

Comment: This could be done with healhcheck and failover which redirects to a static page?

Comment: You would have to have one machine online which will accept and hold the incoming connection while your instance is starting. Which would need to be, well, some sort of web server instance. The only reasonable thing here would be if your primary instance is a very expensive large instance; then you could continuously pay for the smallest, cheapest possible instance as a proxy which accepts connections at any time, and controls the bigger instance as needed.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to make an API call in javascript from the static website (triggered from unhealthy healthcheck), ping the instance and redirect when online?

Answer (score 5):

**DISCLAIMER**: only some theoretical thoughts

Main idea: a landing page using S3 (static website), visiting this page will trigger an Lambda script.This Lambda script will launch the instance.

#### More details:

1. an Amazon S3 static website with a landing page + javascript to:

   - make a call to Amazon API Gateway
   - test if the instance is ready
   - redirect to proper page when everything is ready
   - maybe some url/javascript tricks to avoid the instance to be started by crawlers and bots, scanners etc
2. an Amazon API Gateway: only using to trigger an event for Amazon Lambda
3. an Amazon lambda script used for launching your instance, if is not running.

Depending on your needs, you can try to go serverless like here: https://gofore.com/en/going-serverless-with-amazon-s3-and-lambda/

Comment: Sorry for late reply but this looks like a really good idea in theory! I will test this as soon as I have time and will report it back :)

Comment: @LaurentF have you managed to get this to work? It does sound plausible!

Comment: @MrfksIV I haven't tried it yet (lack of time) but I believe this would work

Answer (score 0):

You can use AutoScaling group. Set the scaling rules as per your need and that's it.

While adding the instance (scaling up) you can use 'Add' 1 instance and while removing the instance (scaling down) you can use 'Set to' 0 instance.

However keep in mind that when the instances are 0 and when the request comes in, that request will not be served but it can just trigger the scale up so that subsequent request can be served after the instance has warmed up.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am guessing that when the instance is 0 while the request is being made it will display a blank or error page. Any way of displaying a loading page until the instance has warmed up?

Comment: No. That's not possible